# File transferred via TFTP has different size than on host

Tags: java, android, tftp

For quite long time now I'm struggling with handling TFTP protocol in my Android app. Its main feature is downloading files from custom designed device which hosts TFTP server.

I was browsing internet hoping to find some good, already written, implementation. First I've tried with TFTP library which is part of Apache Commons. Unfortunately no luck - constant timeouts or even complete freeze. After some further research I found some code on github - [please take a look](https://github.com/tiggreen/java-tftp-client). I've adopted code to Android and after some tweaking I managed to finally receive some files.

Creator of the device stated, that block size should be exactly 1015 bytes. So I increased package size to 1015 and updated creating read request packet method:

```
DatagramPacket createReadRequestPacket(String strFileName) {
    byte[] filename = strFileName.getBytes();
    byte[] mode = currentMode.getBytes();
    int len = rOpCode.length + filename.length + mode.length + 2;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(len);
    try {
        outputStream.write(rOpCode);
        outputStream.write(filename);
        byte term = 0;
        outputStream.write(term);
        outputStream.write(mode); // "octet"
        outputStream.write(term);
        outputStream.write("blksize".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(term);
        outputStream.write("1015".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(term);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] readPacketArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return new DatagramPacket(readPacketArray, readPacketArray.length, serverAddr, port);
}
```

Chunks are being downloaded, but there is one major issue - files I'm downloading are in parts, 512kB each (except last one), and each part I receive on Android device is around 0,5kB larger. It seems like there is one byte more each time or one whole append more. Apparently I don't understand it completely and I'm missing something.

This is my method for file receiving:

```
    byte previousBlockNumber = (byte) -1;
    try {
        PktFactory pktFactory;
        DatagramSocket clientSocket;
        byte[] buf;
        DatagramPacket sendingPkt;
        DatagramPacket receivedPkt;

        System.out.print(ftpHandle);

        if (isConnected) {
            System.out.println("You're already connected to " + hostname.getCanonicalHostName());
        }
        try {
            hostname = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            if (!hostname.isReachable(4000)) {
                System.out.println("Hostname you provided is not responding. Try again.");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("tftp: nodename nor servname provided, or not known");
            return false;
        }
        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        pktFactory = new PktFactory(PKT_LENGTH + 4, hostname, TFTP_PORT);
        System.out.println("Connecting " +
                hostname.getCanonicalHostName() + " at the port number " + TFTP_PORT);
        isConnected = true;
        ftpHandle = "tftp@" + hostname.getCanonicalHostName() + "> ";

        System.out.println("mode " + PktFactory.currentMode);

        if (!isConnected) {
            System.out.println("You must be connected first!");
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        buf = new byte[PKT_LENGTH + 4];

        /* Sending the reading request with the filename to the server. **/
        try {
            /* Sending a RRQ with the filename. **/
            System.out.println("Sending request to server.");
            sendingPkt = pktFactory.createReadRequestPacket(filename);
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(4500);
            clientSocket.send(sendingPkt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Connection with server failed");
        }
        boolean receivingMessage = true;

        while (true) {
            try {
                receivedPkt = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                clientSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
                clientSocket.receive(receivedPkt);

                byte[] dPkt = receivedPkt.getData();
                byte[] ropCode = pktFactory.getOpCode(dPkt);

                /* rPkt either a DATA or an ERROR pkt. If an error then print the error message and
                 * terminate the program finish get command. **/
                if (ropCode[1] == 5) {
                    String errorMsg = pktFactory.getErrorMessage(dPkt);
                    System.out.println(errorMsg);
                    return false;
                }

                if (receivedPkt.getLength() < PKT_LENGTH + 4 && ropCode[1] == 3) {
                    byte[] fileDataBytes = pktFactory.getDataBytes(dPkt);
                    outputStream.write(fileDataBytes);
                    if (isListFile) {
                        listBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
                    } else {
                        FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(Constants.EEG_DATA_PATH.concat("file.bin"), true);
                        // Let's get the last data pkt for the current transfering file.
                        fstream.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
                        fstream.close();
                    }

                    // It's time to send the last ACK message before Normal termination.
                    byte[] bNum = pktFactory.getBlockNum(dPkt);
                    DatagramPacket sPkt = pktFactory.createAckPacket(bNum, receivedPkt.getPort());
                    clientSocket.send(sPkt);

                    disconnect();
                    return true;
                }

                if (ropCode[1] == 3) {
                    if (receivingMessage) {
                        System.out.println("Receiving the file now..");
                        receivingMessage = false;
                    }
                    byte[] bNum = pktFactory.getBlockNum(dPkt);

                    //I've added this if and it reduces file size a little (it was more than 0,5kB bigger)
                    if (previousBlockNumber != bNum[1]) {
                        byte[] fileDataBytes = pktFactory.getDataBytes(dPkt);
                        previousBlockNumber = bNum[1];
                        outputStream.write(fileDataBytes);
                    }

                    /* For each received DATA pkt we need to send ACK pkt back. **/
                    DatagramPacket sPkt = pktFactory.createAckPacket(bNum, receivedPkt.getPort());
                    clientSocket.send(sPkt);
                }
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                disconnect();
                System.out.println("Server didn't respond and timeout occured.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what was wrong. That strange behavior was result of this line when last packet was received:

```
byte[] fileDataBytes = pktFactory.getDataBytes(dPkt);
```

Returned array size was always equal to specified packet length, even if received data was smaller. In my case last packet was 0 bytes (+4 bytes for tftp), but even then extra 512 bytes was added to output stream.

To resolve this I overload mentioned method with extra parameter - actual size of received packet when received data size is higher than 4 bytes and lower than specified packet size (512 bytes). This change resulted with getting correct size of array for last packet, so received file has correct size at the end of the operation.